# what is difference between readInt() and available() function of DataInputOutStream in java

Tags: java, android, multithreading, datainputstream

I need to know how to behave readInt() and available() function to read data stream

**e.g:-**
    [{"frame_id":"48","get_person":true,"type":"get_person","sensor_type":"mjpeg","data_size":41,"engine_id":"rtface"}{"type": "GET_PEOPLE_RESP", "people": []}]

Regards
Janaka

Comment: how you stop your reading? can you show your code here

Comment: i am not stopping, when run , it automatically stop. when start thread first time, it read full incoming stream , when read second time, it return only first part of stream.

Comment: What? Both `avaiable()` and `readInt()` return an `int`, not a string (assuming DataInputStream).

Comment: I still cannot get it. Pls paste your code here

Comment: sorry @Carlos Heuberger. . actually  it returned integer value . i just show how value is taken by using that int value

Comment: @Hash Jang added code sample . please see above

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use JSON, this would work.

```
JsonElement e = new JsonParser().parse(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(e.getAsJsonObject().toString());

int dataSize = obj.getInt("data_size");
boolean getPerson = obj.getBoolean("get_person");
String sensorType = obj.getString("sensor_type");
```

Answer (score 0):

> To read data, I have used the `readInt()` function, but it returns part of the incoming stream.

No it doesn't. It returns an integer.

> To take rest of the part, I have used `available()`.

Why? It doesn't 'take the rest' of anything, let alone 'part'. It 'returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read without blocking'. See the Javadoc.

> It returns the rest of the part

No it doesn't.

> and stops the thread

No it doesn't.

> when it comes again into `readInt()` position inside looping in the sending thread.

Incomprehensible.

> Full Incoming stream:-

```
{"frame_id":"48","get_person":true,"type":"get_person","sensor_type":"mjpeg","data_size":41,"engine_id":"rtface"}{"type": "GET_PEOPLE_RESP", "people": []}
```

> `readInt()` return:

```
{"frame_id":"48","get_person":true,"type":"get_person","sensor_type":"mjpeg","data_size":41,"engine_id":"rtface"}
```

Nonsense. `readInt()` returns an integer, not a string.

> `available()` return:

```
{"type": "GET_PEOPLE_RESP", "people": []}
```

Nonsense. `available()` returns an integer, not a string.

> how to control this?

How to control what?

**EDIT**

Now that you've posted your code, you are making the fairly common mistake of assuming that TCP is a message-oriented protocol, which it isn't, and that `available()` can be used to delimit messages, which it can't. If you want messages, you have to delimit them yourself somehow: or else just treat the input as a byte-stream, which it is, and hand over to another parser, such as a JSON stream parser, and let it do the figuring.

Comment: your reply was helped to modify my question .